# Getting back an NSArray but expecting NSDictionary from JSON

Tags: ios, json

My JSON is below and I'm parsing it like:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

When I do `[jsonDict objectForKey:@"contactPoints"]` I'm getting back an NSArray of NSDictionary objects (one for each contact point with a single key/value pair) instead of a single dictionary object with 3 keys like "website", "email", "phone" and their values.

Why is that? Or how do I structure my JSON better to have an embedded object like contactPoints.

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "contactPoints": {
        "website": "http://www.asdf.com",
        "email": "asdf@gmail.com",
        "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "deliveryHours": {
        "Monday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Tuesday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Wednesday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Thursday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Friday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Saturday": "9:00am - 12:00am",
        "Sunday": "9:00am - 12:00am"
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Looks like a cached data issue. NSURLRequest was caching the page (which I was changing rapidly during development). Parsing is working as expected now.

Comment: Show us an NSLog for the original dictionary that you are getting. BTW. What you posted isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @gnasher729 Right I was missing a quote in the json in this question. Fixed now, but that is unrelated (copy paste error).

Comment: The JSON you posted here would serialize into an `NSDictionary` as you expect. I suspect that the app isn't actually receiving that JSON.

Comment: Actually look at the received JSON, radical concept for sure but worthwhile.

Comment: @Zaph what's up with the tone? Why are you certain I haven't looked at that. Using a static json file on my own webserver.

Comment: Because you say you are getting back an array and the example JSON is a dictionary. But what needs to be looked at is what is being **received**, not what is on the website. Try: `NSLog(@"data as string: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` Or use Charles Proxy to see the actual data.

Comment: Yeah, I'll check it out. Maybe web page was getting cached or something. Trying now with NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData . So basically, it sounds like I'm not crazy. My Json should work the way I expect it and something else must be wrong.

Comment: Ok, seems to be working now. Must have been cached data, although I don't remember ever having that data as an array ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to caching. After changing to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData policy that fixed the issue. I had been rapidly changing the JSON file during development which caused the problem.

The json posted in the question does return a dictionary for contactPoints and deliveryHours.

Answer (score 0):

As i see, there are no array in your JSON script. When you call `[jsonDict objectForKey:@"contactPoints"]` it will return a NSDictionary, not a NSArray

```
NSDictionary* contactPoints = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"contactPoints"];
NSString *website= [contactPoints objectForKey:@"website"];
```

Hope this helps!